# AngularJS throws Error: [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I installed a project from work on my personal computer and only on my machine I get this runtime error. I personally think it has to do with the way the code is compiled.
My question is why the error appears on my machine only?

```
Error: [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported.
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.7/ng/cpws
```

First thing I checked to see if the node and npm versions are the same and they are:

```
node: v8.11.3
npm: 5.6.0
OS: Windows 10
```

The piece of code that generates this error is using `$scope.$watch(object, callback, true)`. After looking on the angular documentation I deleted the third parameter which seemed to be the trouble maker. After that, I encountered other problems so I asked myself why on my machine (which from an environment perspective is the same) the error appears and I stopped modifying the code and start looking on the building part.

I don't know if this will help you but the page that generates the error contains a form build using angular-formly.
Also, we are using `laravel mix` to compile the code.

**UPDATE**

I just updated the node and npm version. At first, I had some issues with the node-sass package but I solved it.
I still have the errors. :(

```
node: v11.10.0
npm: 6.8.0
```

Comment: What is the `object` you're watching?

Comment: @MichaelLynch the object is the actual form. It is something like ```$scope.$watch(`model.${field.key}`, callback)```. I just don't understand why on my personal computer I have this strange runtime error and on the server and on the other computer, it does not appear.
Same code and same environment. I will try to update the node and npm versions today and come back with what will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to recheck if the correct version of angularjs is loaded for you. Many boilerplates declare the angular dependency using something like:

```
...
"angular": "^1.6.7",
...
```

When npm sees this it will load the latest MINOR version if the library is not in node_modules directory. If it is in the node_modules directory and it is greater or equal to 1.6 it will leave it as is. Having a package-lock file might save you from this issue if you actually commit it in the version control system that you use.

This is problematic because loading the 1.7 version might bring in backward incompatible changes (angularjs does not respect semver).